# Converting 'float' to 'byte[4]' and back to 'float' in .NET Micro Framework

Tags: c#, embedded, .net-micro-framework

What's the best way to convert a `float` to a `byte[4]` and then back to a 'float'?

I am doing this in C# [.NET Micro Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Micro_Framework), so there is no `BitConverter` available for my use.

Comment: be careful of endianness (the link from @Mitch shows a BitConverter class that uses little endian)

Comment: The platform that encodes the float does not have any sort of BitConverter class. Nothing that uses a BitConverter class of any type will work.

Comment: Nevermind, looks like it's open source, I can just extract the bits out that I need.

Comment: These floats are now diamonds.

Comment: So far, nothing I have tried has really worked. Can anyone suggest a answer that uses pure bitwise operations?

Comment: I'm assuming you tried the class from the previously mentioned link (which supposedly was written for C# .NETMF). Please explain how it didn't work: Which functions did you try? and what did you expect for output?

Comment: I can't use it because these bytes are getting exchanged between two targets. One of which is not running NETMF. They are being encoded on one and decoded on the other. The other target is an Arduino.

Comment: You might have an endianness mismatch; one is encoding in little endian while the other is decoding in big endian. You'll have to modify the class to allow specifying endianness, and pick the same endianness on both platforms.

Comment: @Jimmy Of all the nonsense. I'm on a horse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've modified the `BitConverter` class from [a Netduino implementation](http://forums.netduino.com/index.php?/topic/308-bitconverter) to allow endianness specification (it's not the "best way", but it works). If the byte array is sent over the network, I would use `BigEndian`. Just a reminder that `unsafe` is not officially supported in NETMF.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace netduino
{
    public static class BitConverter
    {
        public static byte[] GetBytes(uint value)
        {
            return new byte[4] { 
                    (byte)(value & 0xFF), 
                    (byte)((value >> 8) & 0xFF), 
                    (byte)((value >> 16) & 0xFF), 
                    (byte)((value >> 24) & 0xFF) };
        }

        public static unsafe byte[] GetBytes(float value)
        {
            uint val = *((uint*)&value);
            return GetBytes(val);
        }

        public static unsafe byte[] GetBytes(float value, ByteOrder order)
        {
            byte[] bytes = GetBytes(value);
            if (order != ByteOrder.LittleEndian)
            {
                System.Array.Reverse(bytes);
            }
            return bytes;
        }

        public static uint ToUInt32(byte[] value, int index)
        {
            return (uint)(
                value[0 + index] << 0 |
                value[1 + index] << 8 |
                value[2 + index] << 16 |
                value[3 + index] << 24);
        }

        public static unsafe float ToSingle(byte[] value, int index)
        {
            uint i = ToUInt32(value, index);
            return *(((float*)&i));
        }

        public static unsafe float ToSingle(byte[] value, int index, ByteOrder order)
        {
            if (order != ByteOrder.LittleEndian)
            {
                System.Array.Reverse(value, index, value.Length);
            }
            return ToSingle(value, index);
        }

        public enum ByteOrder
        {
            LittleEndian,
            BigEndian
        }

        static public bool IsLittleEndian
        {
            get
            {
                unsafe
                {
                    int i = 1;
                    char* p = (char*)&i;

                    return (p[0] == 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace BitConverterTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] msbFirst = new byte[] { 0x42, 0xF6, 0xE9, 0xE0 };
            byte[] lsbFirst = new byte[] { 0xE0, 0xE9, 0xF6, 0x42 };
            const float f = 123.456789F;

            byte[] b = netduino.BitConverter.GetBytes(f, netduino.BitConverter.ByteOrder.BigEndian);
            for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
            {
                Debug.Assert(msbFirst[i] == b[i], "BitConverter.GetBytes(float, BigEndian) i=" + i);
            }

            Debug.Assert(f == netduino.BitConverter.ToSingle(msbFirst, 0, netduino.BitConverter.ByteOrder.BigEndian));

            Console.WriteLine("All tests passed");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The conversion from `uint` to `float` (and reverse) can be done with "safe" code as well (though I don't know if this is possible on the NETMF or not).

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct UIntFloat
{       
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public float FloatValue;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public uint IntValue;        
}

public static float ToSingle(byte[] value, int index)        
{           
    uint i = ToUInt32(value, index);            
    return ToSingle(i);
}

public static float ToSingle(uint value)
{
    UIntFloat uf = new UIntFloat();
    uf.IntValue = value;
    return uf.FloatValue;
}
```

Comment: Does it make any difference if the other variable is a uint or int?

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me, may not be the most complete answer but simple

```
void floatToByte(GLubyte b[], float n)
{
unsigned int val = *((unsigned int*)&n);

b[0] = (GLubyte)(val  & 0xFF);
b[1] = (GLubyte)((val >> 8) & 0xFF);
b[2] = (GLubyte)((val >> 16) & 0xFF);
b[3] = (GLubyte)((val >> 24) & 0xFF);   
}



float byteToFloat(GLubyte b[])
{
unsigned int ret =  (unsigned int)(b[0] << 0 | b[1] << 8 | b[2] << 16 | b[3] << 24);
float r = *(((float*)&ret));
return r;
}
```

Comment: this isn't even C#!