# Convert float to byte array in C# NETMF (NETMF doesn't have BitConverter)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-micro-framework

I have a C# [NETMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Micro_Framework) project, and I need to convert a `float` to a `byte[]` and vice versa. The problem is, NETMF doesn't have `System.BitConverter` like .NET, so I can't really find any way of doing it without going low level and doing it myself.

I have always programmed high-level ([Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29), [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29), etc.) and have only dabbled in C++, so I don't really know how to turn a float into a byte array.

What would some sample code of a boilerplate function for doing this look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Converting float to 'byte\[4\]' and back to 'float' in NETMF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742910/converting-float-to-byte4-and-back-to-float-in-netmf)*.

Answer (score 4):

The [`StructLayoutAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx) is [supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee436421.aspx) by the .NET Micro Framework, so you could use a C++ style union to get the bytes of a float (and the other way around too):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]  
public struct FloatUnion
{ 
    [FieldOffset(0)] public float Value;
    [FieldOffset(0)] public byte Byte0;
    [FieldOffset(1)] public byte Byte1;
    [FieldOffset(2)] public byte Byte2;
    [FieldOffset(3)] public byte Byte3;

    public byte[] ToByteArray()
    {
        return new[] { Byte0, Byte1, Byte2, Byte3 };
    }

    public static byte[] FloatToBytes(float value)
    {
        return new FloatUnion { Value = value }.ToByteArray();
    }

    public static float BytesToFloat(byte[] bytes)
    {
        if (bytes.Length != 4) throw new ArgumentException("You must provide four bytes.");
        return new FloatUnion { Byte0 = bytes[0], Byte1 = bytes[1], Byte2 = bytes[2], Byte3 = bytes[3] }.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: With the note that this may need modification to take into account endianness.

Comment: @NPSF3000: Indeed. Fortunately this can be easily adjusted.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek FieldOffset is not present in the .NETMF (System.Runtime.InteropServices)

Comment: @LordofScripts: Yes, it seems so.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the integers (Int32, Byte, UInt64, etc) where each value is easily determined from the status of each bit in the integer's bytes, there is no intuitive representation of a floating-point number in binary, so the IEEE defined a specification for floating point numbers: [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point). Suffice to say, it isn't simple, but following the rules in the specification will allow you to serialize a .NET System.Single and System.Double instance to a series of bytes.

The desktop .NET Framework actually cheats here. The GetBytes(Single) function actually just casts the Single instance to an Int32 then copies the raw bytes into a 4-byte array using raw pointers. However you can't take this useful shortcut because the micro framework does not support pointers - even worse: the MF doesn't include BinaryWriter either. You'll have to roll your own IEEE-754 serializer I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `BinaryWriter` on top of a `MemoryStream`.

Comment: BinaryWriter isn't included the Micro Framework ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx )

Comment: Even so, the BinaryWriter serializes Single using pointers and unsafe code too - I don't think that would work even if the BinaryWriter class was copied over using the Portable Class Library feature.