# How can I encode two numbers in a single Integer?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, floating-point, bitmask

I have the need to store a range of values (like 25-50 or 100-200), however to avoid a lot of database re-design and other work, I want to use a single `Int32` to store both these numbers.  I realize that I would only then have 16 bits for each number, but that's fine.

So, with two integer values this is pretty easy.  I can do something like:

```
int mask = 50; //Right bits will have 50
mask |= (25 << 16); //Left bits will have 25

Console.WriteLine("Mask is: {0}", mask);
Console.WriteLine("Left is: {0}", (mask >> 16));
Console.WriteLine("Right is: {0}", (mask & 0xFFFF));
```

Now, I have the right 16 bits storing the value 50, and the left 16 bits storing the value 25.

**So what's the question?**

Now, I want to use the same technique but I want to store two non-integers.  For example, 1.5 and 1.75, or 2.00 and 2.25.  .NET doesn't seem to support bit shift operators on `float`, `single`, `double` or `decimal`.  **Plus, I need to also read these values eventually in Javascript** so it's doubtful whatever bit encoding floating points use would be completely compatible between platforms.

What's the best way to do this?  One approach I'm considering is just using integers, but dividing everything by 1000.  That would give me 3 decimal point precision in both numbers, though I'd have to store the whole thing as a `long` to store anything over 65.  I'm not sure if this is the best approach though.  Maybe there's something easy I'm missing.

Comment: The something easy you're missing might be changing your database schema.

Comment: the best way is to go ahead and add the appropriate columns to the database.  god help the next poor guy who has to deal with this hack.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin - changing the DB schema is the easy part.  Changing the ORM code and all the associated data structures is the part turning into a complete nightmare.  I spent a few days on it, and got almost no where so I'm looking at different approaches.

Comment: I think that's what people call [technical debt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt). And if you go with the hack instead of just correcting the design problem, you're just putting off the repayment of that debt (which is growing with compound interest all the while). Each hack is compounding the problem even more, so that eventually the only option is a complete rewrite, which will cost even more time/money.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté - In the end, your comment swayed me against this idea.  I decided to stop trying to fit a round peg into a square hole, and instead just re-drill the hole to fit the peg correctly.  It took about 2 days, but the design is now superior because of it.  I think it's still a decent question though, as someone out there might have a legitimate reason to encode two floating points in a single int.

Comment: @Mike: It _is_ a legitimate question. And I think even in cases where it's a hack, it might still be unavoidable (e.g. it took you 2 days to complete the redesign, but a non-negotiable deadline could have been 1 day away). That's why _all_ software projects have technical debt, and not always due to incompetence. But it's just important to recognize that you _are_ accruing a debt that grows the longer it's unpaid. Because it takes a very disciplined developer/team to actually schedule regularly allotted time to repay that technical debt after the deadline has been met.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A little math could solve that.

First fix your precision, say 2 digits and your numbers range till 1000

```
both = Math.Round(num1, 2) * 10000 + Math.Round(num2, 2);
```

First 4 digits are for num1 and then you have num2.

You can get them back reversing the process.

Comment: I think this is the approach I'd go with as well, especially since it would be fully Javascript compatible.  If I decide to go this route at all.  I had no idea this question would be so controversial!

Comment: It would be difficult to maintain, imagine if you had to search on one of those columns tomorrow. There are times when such approaches do make sense, like packing multiple variables in one to save transmission bytes. Document the hack well, so the next guy is not dumbfounded.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you do not have lots of decimal digits the easiest solution would be multiplying each number with whatever amount of decimals you want, then converting both numbers to ints, performing your bit operations and then storing the result in your database.

When reading them you simply split the number and then divide it by the factor you used before.

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking is called in mathematics *[pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics,%20a%20pairing%20function,same%20cardinality%20as%20natural%20numbers.)*.

There are many pairing functions, amoung which there are Goedel's, Cantor's, etc.

Godel p.f. is not practical to encode nested languages, but it's excellent for plain languages with not so many symbols.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you have BitConverter.  You can convert the Float value from the DB to a byte array in code, then do whatever you need with it, then convert it back to Float before saving it to the DB.

See the post below for an example.

[C#: Convert Byte array into a float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619664/c-convert-byte-array-into-a-float)

Comment: Cutting bits without knowing what they do to shorten it into 16 bits will not work. Floats are a tad peculiar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the float to byte[] conversion from the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742910/float-to-byte4-and-back-to-float).

When you have a byte-array, you can use your masking technique.

Comment: but the masking works for byte-arrays! Convert the float to byte[] and then do the masking!

Comment: But how are you going to revert it and get the exact same float?

Comment: Follow the link in my answer. In the answer to that question you will find Methods for byte[]-to-float and float-to-byte[] conversion as well.

Comment: How are you going to pack two `byte[4]`'s a single `Int32`/`Uint32`/`byte[4]`.