# How to convert 2 dimensional float array to byte array and viceversa

Tags: c#

I have data in the form of

`float [1000,2]` data.

I want to convert that data in the form of byte []b.

and again I want to convert `byte []b` to 2 dimensional array of `float [1000,2]` data

I want to do this because i can save data to server in the form of byte easily.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742910/converting-float-to-byte4-and-back-to-float-in-netmf

Comment: Do you expect four bytes per float?

Comment: i want to convert 2 dimensional float array(float [1000,2] data) to one dimensional byte array(mean byte []b)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use these methods. They use simple programing structures and I think it won't be hard to understand them. The first method converts the float 2Dimansional array into one array of bytes. It first declares byte array and then each float value converts to 4 bytes and stores them into the big byte array.

```
    public byte[] ToByteArray(float[,] nmbs)
    {
        byte[] nmbsBytes = new byte[nmbs.GetLength(0) * nmbs.GetLength(1)*4];
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nmbs.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < nmbs.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                byte[] array = BitConverter.GetBytes(nmbs[i, j]);
                for (int m = 0; m < array.Length; m++)
                {
                    nmbsBytes[k++] = array[m];
                }
            }
        }
        return nmbsBytes;
    }
```

The second method converts from byte array to 2Dimensional float array. It first declares the array and then each four bytes converts to the float number which is afterwards stored to the specified position in 2D float array.

```
    public float[,] ToFloatArray(byte [] nmbsBytes)
    {
        float[,] nmbs = new float[nmbsBytes.Length /4 / 2, 2];
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nmbs.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < nmbs.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                nmbs[i, j] = BitConverter.ToSingle(nmbsBytes,k);
                k += 4;
            }
        }
        return nmbs;
    }
```